# Common equivalent conditions for Cohen-Macaulayness of a ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

I know the fact that a local ring $(R,m)$ with $\dim(R)=d$ is Cohen-Macaulay (C-M) if and only if any one of the following holds:

1) $\operatorname{grade}(m)=\operatorname{height}(m)$

2) $\operatorname{grade}(p)=\operatorname{height}(p)$ for all prime ideals $p$ of $R$

3) $\operatorname{grade}(I)=\operatorname{height}(I)$ for all ideals $I$ of $R$

How  could we deduce from the above that:

> A ring $R$ is C-M if and only if any of the above conditions holds for $R$? (Of course, the first condition for any all maximal ideal ideals $m$ of $R$.)

I also know that $R$ is C-M if and only if $R_m$ is so, for any maximal ideal $m$ of $R$.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ be a maximal ideal of $R$.

If $R_m$ is CM, then $\operatorname{depth}R_m=\dim R_m$, and therefore $\operatorname{grade}m=\operatorname{ht}m$.

Conversely, assume that $\operatorname{grade}m=\operatorname{ht}m$. Then $\operatorname{depth}R_m=\dim R_m$, that is, $R_m$ is CM.

(I've used that $\operatorname{grade}m=\operatorname{grade}mR_m$ and $\operatorname{ht}m=\dim R_m$.)

Comment: Thanks! And how for the equivalence of "$R$ is C-M" to the condition (3)?

Comment: Do you mean how to prove that $R$ CM implies grade = height for any ideal?

Comment: If this is the question, then use that the grade of $I$ is the minimum of $\operatorname{depth}R_p$ for $p\supseteq I$ and its height is the minimum of $\dim R_p$ for $p\supseteq I$.